# How to Switch Bootstrap Tabbable Nab Tabs to Drop-Down in Mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can you please let me know if it is possible to change the bootstrap tabbable tabs to Drop-Down tabs like what we have in responsive Nav bar? I have a few tabs and they looks ugly in Mobile view so I think to have them like drop-down.

Code Updated:

```
<div class="well">
 <div class="tabbable">
  <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">HOME... </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade in " id="profile">PROFILE... </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade in " id="messages">MESSAGES...</div> 
  <div class="tab-pane fade in " id="settings">SETTING... </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have for tabs?

Comment: Hi Skelly, I added the code on the first post